# Tkinter (Python) Layout Issues

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI application that lets you view the quote of the day from different quote of the day servers. I'm using Tkinter with the grid layout (I used pack before, and that didn't go so well). Here's what I have right now:

[image: QOTD Viewer Current Layout]

My problem is that I want the text box and the 'View QOTD' button to be next to the 'Server Address' label. I have tried several things, and they didn't work. My code is below:

```
from Tkinter import *

class qotdApp:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.prompt = Label(frame, text="Server Address: ")
        self.prompt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.sAEntry = Entry(frame)
        self.sAEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.go = Button(frame, text="View QOTD", command=self.reportAddress)
        self.go.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

        self.viewQuote = Text(frame, height=5)
        self.viewQuote.grid(row=1, rowspan=3)

        frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=4)

    def reportAddress(self):

        print self.sAEntry.get()


root = Tk(className='quote of the day viewer')
app = qotdApp(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using `rowspan` when you should be using `columnspan`. You want it to span the three columns, not three rows.